# Why won't Isabelle simplify the body of my "if _ then _ else" construct?

Tags: isabelle

I have the following Isabelle goal:

```
lemma "⟦ if foo then a ≠ a else b ≠ b ⟧ ⟹ False"
```

None of the tactics `simp`, `fast`, `clarsimp`, `blast`, `fastforce`, etc. make any progress on the goal, despite it being quite simple.

Why doesn't Isabelle just simplify the body of the `if` construct so that both "a ≠ a" and "b ≠ b" become `False`, and hence solve the goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The `if_weak_cong` congruence rule

By default, Isabelle includes a set of "congruence rules" that affect where simplification takes place. In particular, a default congruence rule is `if_weak_cong`, as follows:

```
b = c ⟹ (if b then x else y) = (if c then x else y)
```

This congruence rule tells the simplifier to simplify the condition of the `if` statement (the `b = c`) but never attempt to simplify the body of the `if` statement.

You can either disable the congruence rule using:

```
apply (simp cong del: if_weak_cong)
```

or override it with an alternative (more powerful) congruence rule:

```
apply (simp cong: if_cong)
```

Both of these will solve the above lemma.

### Why `if_weak_cong` is in the default cong set

Another reasonable question might be: "Why would `if_weak_cong` be in the default congruence set if it causes problems like the above?"

One motivation is to prevent the simplifier from unfolding a recursive function infinitely, such as in the following case:

```
fun fact where
    "fact (n :: nat) = (if n = 0 then 1 else (n * fact (n - 1)))"
```

in this case,

```
lemma "fact 3 = 6"
  by simp
```

solves the goal, while

```
lemma "fact 3 = 6"
  by (simp cong del: if_weak_cong)
```

sends the simplifier into a loop, because the right-hand-side of the `fact` definition continually unfolds.

This second scenario tends to occur more frequently than the scenario in the original question, which motivates `if_weak_cong` being the default.

Comment: Note that rules like `fact.simps` above often lead to non-terminating simplifier runs even with `if_weak_cong` because of the splitting rule `split_if`, which is applied when the simplifer can not make any progress otherwise.

Comment: If we use `if_cong` as a congruence rule, the simplifier is able to take the condition into account when simplifying the branches. For this consider the lemma `"⟦ if foo then ¬foo else foo ⟧ ⟹ False"`. Without any congruence rule, the simplifier cannot solve this goal (since neither `foo` nor `¬foo` can be simplified on its own). However, when using `if_cong`, the simplifier can use `foo` as an assumption for the first branch and `¬foo` as an assumption for the second branch.

Comment: Is there a way to list all congruence rules? It seems that one should review them when the simplifier does not do what you expect?

Comment: @Joachim Breitner: `print_simpset` has a section "congruences". Maybe that is what you are searching for.

Answer (score 5):

### Split rules

Besides case analysis and congruence rules, there is a third way to solve this goal with the simplifier: The splitter. The splitter allows the simplifier to perform a limited form of case analysis on its own. It is only run when the term cannot be simplified any further on its own (splitting cases can easily lead to an explosion of the goal).

The lemma `split_if_asm` instructs the splitter to split an `if` in the assumptions:

```
lemma "⟦ if foo then a ≠ a else b ≠ b ⟧ ⟹ False"
  by (simp split: split_if_asm)
```

A single-step split can be performed with the `split` method:

```
lemma "⟦ if foo then a ≠ a else b ≠ b ⟧ ⟹ False"
  apply (split split_if_asm)
  apply simp_all
  done
```

Note that the rule to split an `if` in the conclusion (`split_if`) is part of the default setup.

BTW, for each datatype `t`, the datatype package provides the split rules `t.split` and `t.split_asm` which provide case analysis for `case` expressions involving the type `t`.

Comment: There is also the ruleset `t.splits` which contains both `t.split` and `t.split_asm`

Answer (score 4):

Another natural way of making progress in a proof containing `if _ then _ else _` is case analysis on the condition, e.g.,

```
lemma "(if foo then a ~= a else b ~= b) ==> False"
  by (cases foo) simp_all
```

or if `foo` is not a free variable, but bound by an outermost meta-level universal quantifier (as is often the case in apply-scripts):

```
lemma "!!foo. (if foo then a ~= a else b ~= b) ==> False"
  apply (case_tac foo)
  apply simp_all
done
```

Unfortunately, if `foo` is bound by another kind of quantifier, e.g.

```
lemma "ALL foo. (if foo then a ~= a else b ~= b) ==> False"
```

or by a meta-level universal quantifier in a nested assumption, e.g.

```
lemma "True ==> (!!foo. (if foo then a ~= a else b ~= b)) ==> False"
```

neither `cases` nor `case_tac` are applicable.

**Note:** See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13767196/476803) for the (slight) difference between `cases` and `case_tac`.

Answer (score 4):

### Congruence rules

As already noted in the other answers, the `if_weak_cong` congruence rule prevents the simplifier from simplifying the branches of the if statement. In this answer, I want to elaborate a bit on the use of congruence rules by the simplifier.

For further information, see also the chapter about the Simplifier in the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2013/doc/isar-ref.pdf) (in particular section 9.3.2).

Congruence rules control how the simplifier descends into terms. They can be used to limit rewriting and to provide additional assumptions. By default, if the simplifier encounters a function application `s t` it will descend both into `s` and `t` to rewrite them to `s'` and `t'`, before trying to rewrite the resulting term `s' t'`.

For each constant (or variable) c one can register a single congruence rule. The rule `if_weak_cong` is registered by default the constant `If` (which is underlying the `if ... then ... else ...` syntax):

```
?b = ?c ⟹ (if ?b then ?x else ?y) = (if ?c then ?x else ?y)
```

This reads as: "If you encounter a term `if ?b then ?x else ?y` and `?b` can be simplified to `?c`, then rewrite `if ?b then ?x else ?y` to `if ?c then ?x else ?y`". As congruence rules *replace* the default strategy, this forbids any rewriting of `?x` and `?y`.

An alternative to `if_weak_cong` is the strong congruence rule `if_cong`:

```
⟦ ?b = ?c; (?c ⟹ ?x = ?u); (¬ ?c ⟹ ?y = ?v) ⟧
    ⟹ (if ?b then ?x else ?y) = (if ?c then ?u else ?v)
```

Note the two assumptions `(?c ⟹ ?x = ?u)` and `(¬ ?c ⟹ ?y = ?v)`: They tell the simplifier that it may assume that the condition holds (or holds not) when simplifying the left (or right) branch of the if.

As an example, consider the behaviour of the simplifier on the goal

```
if foo ∨ False then ¬foo ∨ False else foo ⟹ False
```

and assume that we know nothing about `foo`. Then,

- `apply simp`: with the rule `if_weak_cong`, this will be simplified to
  `if foo then ¬ foo ∨ False else foo ⟹ False`, only the condition is rewritten
- `apply (simp cong del: if_weak_cong)`: Without any congruence rule, this will be
   simplified to
  `if foo then ¬ foo else foo ⟹ False`, as the condition and the branches are rewritten
- `apply (simp cong: if_cong del: if_cancel)`: With the rule `if_cong`, this goal will
  simplified to
  `if foo then False else False ⟹ False`: The condition `foo ∨ False` will be
  rewritten to `foo`. For the two branches, the simplifier now rewrites
  `foo ⟹ ¬foo ∨ False` and `¬foo ⟹ foo ∨ False`, both of which obviously rewrite to
  False.

  (I removed `if_cancel`, which would usually solve the remaining goal completely)

Comment: Thanks for the informative post. I wonder if it would be helpful to create/answer a new question "How do I use congruence rules" to help people find it?

Comment: If you are explicitly interested in congruence rules, I find it easy to locate the appropriate section in the reference manual (just look for `cong (attribute)` in the index and find a description similar to mine here), so I am not particularly interested in doing that.

Comment: Not so much personally, but I have been trying to seed StackOverflow with some of the questions that I frequently get internally; what you have written here (and under "split rules") would likely also fall into this category. But perhaps it is just better to wait for the questions. `:)`

Comment: I understand (and appreciate) that. What I meant is that this kind question "what do congruence rules do" is easily answered from the manual (in contrast to "why doesn't the simplifier do ...").