# Isabelle: If statement inside a sum

Tags: isabelle

I have a problem with an if-statement within a sum.

I checked the solution in another question on [if statements in isabelle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15627676/why-wont-isabelle-simplify-the-body-of-my-if-then-else-construct)
but it did not help.

Here is an example:

```
theorem dummy:
  fixes a :: "('a::comm_ring_1 poly)" 
    and B :: "(('a::comm_ring_1 poly)^'n∷finite^'n∷finite)"
  shows "1=1"
proof-
  { fix i j
   have "(∑k∈UNIV. if i = k then (B $ i $ j) else 0) = B $ i $ j" sorry
  }
```

How can I prove the lemma where the "sorry" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theorem you are looking for is `setsum_delta`:

```
finite ?S ⟹
(∑k∈?S. if k = ?a then ?b k else 0) =
    (if ?a ∈ ?S then ?b ?a else 0)
```

If you write `k = i` instead of `i = k` in your sum, it can even be solved automatically:

```
have "(∑k∈UNIV. if k = i then (B $ i $ j) else 0) = B $ i $ j" 
    by (simp add: setsum_delta)
```

The `find_theorems` command is very useful for this. If you type

```
find_theorems "∑_∈_. if _ then _ else _"
```

You get `setsum_delta` as one of the matches – that's how I found it.